# Internet is Slow Thru squid proxy when GPO Applied to server

Tags: proxy, squid

I have this problem when GPO applied to workstations with squid proxy on the browsers the internet is slow. I tried a

```
sudo net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

and added on squid.conf

```
dns_v4_first on
```

Applied changes nothing happened.

my server DNS using 4.4.2.1, 4.4.2.2
my squid proxy DNS is 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

I have 60 workstation in our company and i'm using Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS for Squid Proxy.

Comment: Then 60 workstations are all using the Squid proxy at the same time, on the same pool of network resources assigned to the proxy system.  That's typical of dumping more and more internet traffic through a single chokepoint.  They're all fighting for resources on the single system's uplink to the Internet.  Unless you use a load balancer to balance between proxy systems and have multiple, you're piping 61 systems' resources through one single connection (Squid's LAN interface) to the network.

Comment: Google is fine and some websites are ok. But some https websites are running very slow like salesforce.